# Does Fantastical support viewing free/busy information from Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

Or said another way, can I see availability of invitees (and resources would be even better) when creating a new event in Fantastical. I don't see it in the interface anywhere and it is critical for me in scheduling meetings with coworkers.

Mac OS 10.10.5, Fantastical 2.1.5.

Comment: In any case, Fantastical does not seem to allow viewing of free/busy information according to their FAQ. "[Fantastical 2 does not currently support ... viewing the availability of other Exchange users.](https://flexibits.com/fantastical/faq)" Note they are talking about Exchange, but given it is arguably the most popular source of free/busy information. Further confirmation [here](https://twitter.com/flexibits/status/451515863108034561).

Comment: Thanks, Alistair. That is exactly what I was looking for for. Unclear indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Pinging @AlistairMcMillan for a proper answer now that it's clear which product is in play.

Answer (score 1):

Fantastical mention free/busy information (aka availability) in the [FAQ](https://flexibits.com/fantastical/faq) for the Mac version.

> Fantastical 2 does not currently support replying to Exchange
>   invitations, marking Exchange events as private, or viewing the
>   availability of other Exchange users.

They also answered this question about their iPad version through their Flexibits Twitter account back in [April 2014](https://twitter.com/flexibits/status/451515863108034561).

> Sorry, Fantastical 2 for iPad won’t let you view free/busy time for
>   meeting invitees.

Note they are talking about Exchange, but given it is arguably the most popular source of free/busy information its not a huge leap to assume the same for Google Calendar.

**UPDATE 30 March 2016** Flexibits just [released a new version of Fantastical for Mac](https://flexibits.com/blog/2016/03/fantastical-2-2-for-mac-aka-the-massively-big-massively-awesome-update/) (version 2.2) that includes support for viewing free/busy information. As above, they focus on Exchange support, but Google Calendar is mentioned too.

> ... new in version 2.2 is our spiffy invitee availability view. When
>   using a compatible service — such as Google or Exchange — you’ll be
>   able to see your invitees’ availability and let Fantastical instantly
>   schedule a meeting for when you’re all free, saving you the time of
>   coordinating with multiple people. (iCloud does not support
>   availability.)